# Return enum type (not instance) in a function, depending on another enum value

Tags: c#, enums

I would like a function to give me back enum types depending on another enum's value. Here's a simplified and full of imagery example of what I would like to achieve. This leads to an "is a type but is used like a variable" error.

Is there a way to implement such function ?

Thanks a lot !

```
public class MyClass
{
    public enum MondayActivities { ... }
    public enum TuesdayActivities { ... }

    public Enum PossibleActivitiesByDay(DayEnum day)
    {
        switch (day)
        {
            case DayEnum.Monday:
                return MondayActivities ;
            case DayEnum.Tuesday:
                return TuesdayActivities ;
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to return the base type of enum, which you can't do. Instead, specify the enum name before your function name. such as `public Enum MondayActivities PossibleActivitiesByDay(DayEnum day)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do it, but you're not going to like it because the values you get back are going to be more-or-less useless! You wont know what they are.

```
public enum DayEnum{Monday,Tuesday}
public enum MondayActivities { Washing, Ironing }
public enum TuesdayActivities { Cleaning, Hoovering }

public static Array PossibleActivitiesByDay(DayEnum day)
{
    switch (day)
    {
        case DayEnum.Monday:
            return Enum.GetValues(typeof(MondayActivities)) ;
        case DayEnum.Tuesday:
            return Enum.GetValues(typeof(TuesdayActivities )) ;
    }
    return null;
 }
```

Usage:

```
foreach(var value in PossibleActivitiesByDay(DayEnum.Monday))
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/CTUBYA10553

That works, as you can see, in that it prints the name of the returned values, but programatically you have no type-safety - you dont know if its a `MondayActivity` or a `TuesdayActivity`.

Comment: It is not actually an enum but I will be able to go with it since the values are available ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

The answer is pretty much already in your question. Just return wanted enum's type, not value or general-purpose Enum.

```
public Type PossibleActivitiesByDay(DayEnum day)
{
    switch (day)
    {
        case DayEnum.Monday:
            return typeof(MondayActivities) ;
        case DayEnum.Tuesday:
            return typeof(TuesdayActivities) ;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to accept your answer as well, unfortunately I can't accept both... Anyway thanks a lot 'cause your answer was also totally relevant regarding my question !

Answer (score 0):

Even if [Enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx) is a type inside `CLR`, it does not support polymorphism, so you can not abstract it over some hypothetical "base" enum .

The only reasonable solution, I'm afraid, in presented case is to define distinct functions that return concrete enum types.